# Django 'authenticate()' returns None

Tags: python, django, authentication, web

I have done very little modification to the default User model, and yet my login form is refusing to work, because django's authenticate is continually returning none.

I have included all relevant code here (including the error): https://gist.github.com/ianseyer/9941585

And yes, I am using set_password().

It might be worth noting that I am using django-crispy-forms, though the error happens outside of forms.

Comment: try this user.set_password(str(password)); user.save()

Answer (score 0):

You're passing parameters to `create_user` in the wrong order.

Your method expects first_name, last_name, email, password. But you are passing email, first_name, last_name, password. So when you come to authenticate, it's expecting the thing you passed as last_name, not the email.

Comment: changed this, to no avail.